# Java FX using 2 fonts for 2 languages

Tags: css, javafx, fonts

My Java FX application has text in both English and Hebrew, I want to use [Roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto) for the English text and [Noto Sans Hebrew](https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-hebr) for the Hebrew text.

The code I've come up with does not work as described below, Code:

```
// java
Parent root = new VBox() {{
    getChildren().addAll(
        new Label("THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG"),
        new Label("the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"),
        new Label("השפן טעם ביס ואכל קצת גזר חד")
    );
}};
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root) {{
    getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
}});
primaryStage.show();


// style.css
@font-face {
    src: url('Roboto-Regular.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    src: url('NotoSansHebrew-Regular.ttf');
}
.root {
    /* Attempt 1 - it only takes the first one */
    -fx-font-family: "Roboto" "Noto Sans Hebrew";

    /* Attempt 2 - it only takes the last one */
    -fx-font-family: "Roboto";
    -fx-font-family: "Noto Sans Hebrew";
}
```

Comment: You need to target the actual individual `Label`s. This can be done by giving all the English `Label`s one style class while giving all the Hebrew `Label`s another style class. To add a style class use `Node.getStyleClass().add(...)`. Then use the style classes in the CSS file.

Comment: This code is an example, In my real application I do not know which `Node` has which language.